# Column cannot be found during sorting gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, gridview

The problem that occurs is Column cannot be found when sorting is performed. I've tried to sort the gridview with a lot of different code. It have been a week since I start the sorting. I've tried to follow other coding
but the same error still occurs.

```
Protected Sub SortRecords(sender As Object, e As GridViewSortEventArgs)

    Dim dt As New DataTable(GridView1.DataSource)
    Dim SortDir As String = String.Empty
    Dim sortExpression As String = e.SortExpression
    Dim sortedView As DataView = dt.DefaultView


    If sortedView IsNot Nothing Then
        If direction = SortDirection.Ascending Then
            direction = SortDirection.Descending
            SortDir = "Desc"

        Else
            direction = SortDirection.Ascending

            SortDir = "Asc"

        End If
        sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression & " " & SortDir 'error occur on this line

        GridView1.DataSource = sortedView
        GridView1.AllowSorting() = True
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem happens on this line:

```
 sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression & " " & SortDir
```

Comment: And the value of `e.SortExpression` matches a column name of your DataTable?

Comment: it did match the column name on my DataTable.

Comment: it did match but still show the error of cant find column.